I am not able to see folder related permissions under resourcemanager while trying to grant access/roles to a user
I am trying to get a list of folder via API and it says-
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The caller does not have permission",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}
the document says -The caller must have resourcemanager.folders.list permission on the identified parent.
But I am unable to see this permission under resourcemanager while trying to grant access to the user/serviceaccount
Tried to add permission, but unable to see folder related permissions/roles while granting access in IAM.

As per the Official document on Listing all projects and folders in your hierarchy :

You can use list permissions granted at the Organization resource level itself, which avoids issues caused by the user having partial
permissions, which results in some resources being omitted from the
list.
If a user has the list permission but not the get permission
for a particular resource, that resource won't be visible at all in
the Console. However, the resource will be returned in a search using
the API or CLI that specifies the resource's parent. This disparity
between the Console and other methods is a common source of confusion
when trying to scan the resource hierarchy.

As per the official GCP document on Viewing or listing folders and projects: Try using a new installation of gcloud SDK, and it fixes the existing configuration by running gcloud init command which avoids the Permissions issue.
There’s a predefined role for list Folders, the Resource Manager Folder Viewer (roles/resourcemanager.folderViewer), let's use it as an example and focus on the resourcemanager.folders.list permission that comes included in that predefined role. Folder Editor role( roles/resourcemanager.folderEditor) also does the same or you use the Resource Manager API Explorer to set IAM policy directly. Also refer to the official GCP document on Granting roles to enable folder browsing for more details.
You can create a Custom Roles section and create a custom role from it to narrow down the permissions for your users.
Note : You cannot define custom roles at the folder level. If you need to use a custom role within a folder, define the custom role at the organization resource level.
There is an ongoing Feature Request for the similar issue. Follow for further updates.

As mentioned in the documentation, "To view or list folders, you must have the Organization Viewer and Folder Viewer roles".
